# Need SQL query for Goto Report in SSRS with multiple clickable columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to call a detail report when a numeric value(green area) in the summary report is clicked and it displays rows based on the parameters passed to the detail report.

In this case i am passing Brand ,State,ordernumber as parameters to the child report if i want to see the detail rows when i click some value in the CountOfPO column .

In this case please see orange colored cell where 2 is the count and when i click it i get two rows in the child report

i.e in ssrs i rightclicked on CountOfPO column in the summary report-->textbox properties-->action-->GoToReport-->Specified detailed report and provided parameters as @state,@brand,@ordernumber

in the similar way i want to achive for the rest of the two columns in the summary report which are "LateOrders" and "LateOrdersByEmp".

But if i pass the same parameters as @state,@brand,@ordernumber to the columns "LateOrders" or "LateOrdersByEmp", i wont get correct data as these parameters all already in use by the first column "CountOfPO"( and will get the same data returned as it would be for "CountOfPO")

I have other columns(flag colum) in my detailed report query which can uniquely identify 
"LateOrders" and "LateOrdersByEmp" columns so that i can use them as parameters and they can be passed to the details report from the summary report, but need help on how to write the query for the child report based on case conditions .
Kindly help and let me know if i have not explained myself clearly.
[image: Example]

Comment: So apparently your question is not about the report but about `SQL Query`?

Comment: Hi Viking,  yes please

Comment: So can you please remove all the details associated with SSRS and just ask the plain question tagging SQL and asking what we can do to address SQL needs? Will make it easy to understand and attack the issue :)